# Dominant and Injective Morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

As mentioned before, I am self-studying some commutative algebra out of "A Course in Commutative Algebra" by Kemper. In the text, Kemper has the following problem:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be affine varieties over a field $ K$, and let $f: X → Y$ be a morphism with induced
homomorphism $ϕ: K[Y ] → K[X].$ We say that $f$ is dominant if the image
$f(X)$ is dense in $Y$ , i.e., $f(X) = Y$ .

Show that $f$ is dominant if and only if ϕ is injective.

He provides a proof of the forward implication namely,

Assume that $f$ is dominant, and let $ϕ(g) = 0$ with $g ∈ K[Y]$. Viewing $g$
as a regular function $Y → K,$ we have $g\circ f = 0,$ so the restriction of $g $ to
$f(X)$ is zero. Since $g$ is continuous and $f(X)$ is dense, this implies $g = 0$.

I am trying to understand the overall structure of this proof however I had 3 questions regarding some details.

1. In viewing $g: Y \rightarrow K$ as a regular function, how comes he can conclude that  $g\circ f = 0,$?
2. Having  $g \circ f = 0,$, how does this imply that restriction of $g $ to
   $f(X)$ is zero?
3. I see why $g$ is continuous ( I believe here he means continuous in the Zariski Topology), but how does the continuity of $g$ and the fact by the hypothesis $f(X)$ is dense imply that $g = 0$.

Once we have the result that $g = 0$, the injectivity follows immediately. Any help in coming to terms with my 3 questions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to answer your questions:

1. This is just the definition of the morphism $\phi$. Under the assumption that $g\in\ker(\phi)$ this means $g\circ f=0$.
2. $g\circ f=0$ means that for any point $x\in X$, $g(f(x))=0$, so the restriction of $g$ to $f(X)$ is zero.
3. There is the following theorem: Let $T$ be a reduced scheme and $S$ a separated scheme, $U\subset T$ dense open set. Then two morphisms $f,g \colon T\rightarrow S$ that agree on $U$ must be equal. As you are working with affine varieties all of these properties are satisfied, so $g=0$.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! iI have not run into the last theorem yet but it definitely does the trick.

Comment: Just one more question, i thought i resolved the issue as to why $g$ is continuous, but that turned out to be wrong What is the reasoning there?

Comment: Also, I am not too familiar with scheme's. Is this theorem the only lense in which my question to 3 makes sense?

Comment: To question 3: Suppose $f,g\colon X\rightarrow Y$ agree on a dense open set $U$. One can show that $\mathrm{Eq}(f,g)$, the set where $f$ and $g$ agree, is closed. As $U\subset \mathrm{Eq}(f,g)$ it follows that the underlying topological spaces of $\mathrm{Eq}(f,g)$ and $X$ agree.

Comment: Regular functions are always continuous.